# HAproxy to v2ray

Tags: networking, server, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.I have a VPS with v2ray that is proxied behind Cloudflare. Because of the restriction of open ports of Cloudflare, I want to use HAproxy to connect all users via the 443 port on VPS. How can I configure HAproxy to implement such a scenario? Is there something I should do on v2ray and x-ui too?

Topology:

[image: topology]